# Notice: Undefined index: txtQuant - PHP Textbox is undefined using SESSIONS

Tags: php, session-variables

> Notice: Undefined index: txtQuant in E:\wamp\www\ShoppingCartV4\cartv4.php on line 8
>
> Notice: Undefined index: txtQuant in E:\wamp\www\ShoppingCartV4\cartv4.php on line 56

My Update code:

```
 if(isset($_GET["update"]))
    {
    $i = $_GET["update"];
    

    $_SESSION["Qnty"] = $_GET["txtQuant"];
    $_SESSION["amounts"][$i] = $_SESSION["Qnty"][$i];

    }
```

My html code

```
<?php
       if(!empty($_SESSION["products"])){
          for ($i=0; $i< count($_SESSION["products"]); $i++) {
           ?>
           <tr>
           <td><?php echo($_SESSION["products"][$i]); ?></td>
           <td width="10px">&nbsp;</td>
           <td><input type="text" name="txtQuant[]"></td>
           <td width="10px">&nbsp;</td>
           <td><?php echo($_SESSION["amounts"][$i]); ?></td>
           <td width="10px">&nbsp;</td>
           
           
           <td><a href="?update=<?php echo($i); ?>">Update</a></td>
           
           </tr>
           <?php
         }
       }
         ?>
```

How can I resolved this problem? thank you

Comment: I need some suggestions please :(

Comment: Add an `if(!empty($_SESSION["products"]))` above for loop

Comment: It still doesn't work sir ..if(!empty($_SESSION["products"])){
     for ($i=0; $i< count($_SESSION["products"]); $i++) {
      ?>
      <tr>
      <td><?php echo($_SESSION["products"][$i]); ?></td>
      <td width="10px">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="txtQuant[]"></td>
      <td width="10px">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><?php echo($_SESSION["amounts"][$i]); ?></td>
      <td width="10px">&nbsp;</td>  
      <td><a href="?update=<?php echo($i); ?>">Update</a></td>
     
      </tr>
      <?php
     } 

    }
    ?>

Comment: Can you show me the code where you insert value in `$_SESSION["products"]` ?

Comment: Ill edit my post and it will show

Comment: EDITED sir please check thank you

Comment: Friend .. I don't see any code where you insert value like `$_SESSION["products"]='abc'; `.Show the code where you PUT VALUE in this variable

Comment: You need to use a form and a button to submit - not a link.  Have a read through https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp to learn how to use basic forms in PHP.

Comment: $_SESSION["products"] = array("product A", "product B", "product C"); Is this what you are referring to sir?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have that form wrapped in a form tag? You should be wrapping the html code there with  tag. Otherwise there is no form to actually submit and the only thing in your $_GET array will be update.

session_start() is only going to initialize the session, nothing in your code that I see adds txtQuant into the session. If what you are doing is, someone clicks the "Update" link and the submits to the My Update Code snippet you have then it won't work. You need to wrap the table on the bottom there in a form:

```
<?php
       if(!empty($_SESSION["products"])){
?> 
<form>
<?php
          for ($i=0; $i< count($_SESSION["products"]); $i++) {
           ?>
           <tr>
           <td><?php echo($_SESSION["products"][$i]); ?></td>
           <td width="10px">&nbsp;</td>
           <td><input type="text" name="txtQuant[]"></td>
           <td width="10px">&nbsp;</td>
           <td><?php echo($_SESSION["amounts"][$i]); ?></td>
           <td width="10px">&nbsp;</td>

           <td><input type="submit" value="Update"></td>
           <td><input type="hidden" name="update" value="<?php echo($i); ?>" /></td>
           </tr>
           <?php
         }
         ?>
</form>
       <?php
       }
         ?>
```

Comment: The session_start();? Yes I have.. otherwise what form tag do you mean?

Comment: sir can you please type the code please im having difficulties with these :(

Comment: session_start() is only going to initialize the session, nothing in your code that I see adds txtQuant into the session. If what you are doing is, someone clicks the "Update" link and the submits to the My Update Code snippet you have then it won't work. You need to wrap the table on the bottom there in a form:

Comment: How can i then do that sir? A little tutor can you .. thank you.. Your answer seems logical but then i'm new to php

Comment: I tried it sir but it does not work.. but thank you for your response

Comment: I would need much more context to be able to help unfortunately.

Comment: Sir can you briefly explain and tell me what does input hidden does ??

Comment: If you are submitting data to a script and you want the data in the form to be available to the script, you need to wrap the data you want to submit in a <form>. The example I gave you will work if you have the update script in the same file as the html code. Usually they are in separate files. You can submit a form using <form method="get">... or <form method="post">. "get" is when you submit the form and the data in the form is available in the URL....test.com?update=testUpdate&param2=test...etc. Post is when it's sent in the Body of the submission. You are using "get", here.

Comment: A hidden input is a way to pass data in the form without that input being visible on the page. For example, <input type="text" name="txtQuant[]"> is a text box which shows up on the page. A hidden input does not show up on the page but is still submitted with the form.